# Redactor fields not saving more than 252 characters?

Tags: redactor

I haven't set any kind of character limit on my Redactor fields, but when I save a longer body of text, is always cuts it off at 252 characters. See screenshots:

**Before save:**
[image: Before save] 
**After save:**
[image: After save]

Here is my Redactor config:

```
{"buttons":["format","bold","italic","lists","link"],"plugins":["customstyles"],"formatting":["p","h3","h4","blockquote"],"linkNewTab":true,"toolbarFixed":true,"customStyles":{"style":{"dropdown":{"sourceCitation":{"args":"cite"},"strikethrough":{"args":"del"},"superscript":{"args":"sup"},"subscript":{"args":"sub"}}},"clearStyles":{"api":"module.inline.clearformat"}}}
```

EDIT: I have also noticed that if I save it with one spare character remaining, the WYSIWYG is inserting a symbol on save to fill the last spot?! Compare the previous screenshot with the next one and you'll notice i've just knocked off the final 't' and the space has been filled with a random symbol. This is sometimes an ampersand.

**After save minus the last character:**
[image: Added symbol at the end]

Note that this is only happening on a production site and not locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this ended up being that the `field_introduction` column for the Redactor field in the `craft_content` table was set to `varchar(255)`, which means it can only hold 255 characters.

No idea how it got that way. The Redactor field (under its advanced settings) has never had an option to be `varchar(255)`, only `text` and `mediumtext`.

Regardless, going through all of the Redactor field settings and re-saving them correct adjusted the column data type back to `text` and resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the assist, Brad.